# Can you initialize a "cv char[]" with a string literal?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer

The current wording in [[dcl.init.string] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string#1) states:

> An array of ordinary character type, [...] may be initialized by an ordinary string literal, [...], or by an appropriately-typed *string-literal* enclosed in braces.

*Ordinary character type* includes `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` (see [[basic.fundamental]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#def:type,ordinary_character)). It does not include the cv-qualified versions of those types.

From this, it isn't clear whether an array of `const char` or `volatile char` may also be initialized using a string literal, not just an array of `char`. The wording is unclear because it doesn't say:

> An array of *cv* ordinary character type, [...]

This matters in the following situation:

```cpp
const char str[] = "test"; // is this valid?
```

I'm 99% sure that the intention is that you *should* be able to do it. However, is there a paragraph that definitively allows you to, or is this a wording defect?

Comment: That's an array of ordinary character type, `char const[]`.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Eljay I guess the question asks if cv-qualified ordinary character type is still ordinary character type. I'd expect wording like "An array of (possibly cv-qualified) ordinary character type [...]"

Comment: Addendum: a string literal is already const-qualified. Does not say anything about volatile-qualification oc. See https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#1

Comment: @Eljay _What am I missing?_ The definition of ordinary character type

Comment: Related to CWG251, CWG2185, CWG2448